# Generating increasing number of rects after user clicks ready

Tags: javascript, processing

I am trying to make a game. After the player clicks "Ready," I want the "Ready" box to disappear (right now if you click inside the ready box nothing happens and I am unsure why) and have a random rectangle (random x and y coords) to spawn. After the player clicks within the walls of the first rectangle, 2 rectangles spawn and the user must click within those walls. Then 3 rects spawn, 4, etc. I am trying to split the game into scenes however is that necessary? Also, would it be 'better' to use my current button object for the rectangles?   This is over khan academy btw.

```
var randX = random(20, 370);
var randY = random(20, 370);
var randW = random(5, 45);
var randH = random(5, 45);
var currentScene;
var xPos = [];
var yPos = [];

//start button
var Button = function(config) {
    this.x = config.x;
    this.y = config.y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.label = config.label;
};
Button.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(this.x-5, this.y+64, this.width-208, this.height-340, 5);
    fill(252, 18, 29);
    textSize(40);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(this.label, this.x+89, this.y+106);
};
var btn1 = new Button ({
    currentScene: 1,
    x: 111,
    y: 100,
    label: "Ready?"
}
);
btn1.draw();



//generate increasing number of rectangles
var randRect = function() {
    currentScene = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {    
        fill(random(0,255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
        rect(randX[i], randY[i], randW, randH);
}
};

//when player clicks the ready box
draw = function() {
if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX >= 120 && mouseX <= 248 && mouseY <= 263 && mouseY >= 15) {
        if (currentScene === 1){
            randRect();

}
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to relay this to you in Processing, but it should be easy to translate to JS since I'll use some psudeocode.

You should start with a Box class as such:

```
class Box {
   float x, y, w, h;
   boolean hit;

   public Box() {
       //creates a new box with an x-pos, y-pos, a width and a height.
       w = random(0, 200);
       h = random(0, 200);
       x = random(0, width-x);
       y = random(0, height-h);
       hit = false;
    }

   void display() {
      //if the box isn't hit, display it!
      if (!hit) {
      fill(100, 100);
      rect(x, y, w, h);
     }
  }

   void checkHit() {
     //if the box isn't hit, check if it is, and if it is, set "hit" to true.
     if (!hit) {
       if ((mouseX>x) && (mouseX<x+w) && (mouseY>y) && (mouseY<y+h)) {
          hit = true;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

So then create an ArrayList of boxes, two global integers. One to keep track of how many boxes need to be clicked, and one for how many boxes are remaining.

```
ArrayList<Box>boxes;
int boxes_goal;
int boxes_left;
```

In your setup part of your program, instantiate the ArrayList, and add the first box. Then, set your two Integers you created to one, since you wanted to start with one rectangle on the screen.

```
void setup(){ //this method only runs once, at the beginning.
    boxes = new ArrayList<Box>;
    boxes.add(new Box());
    boxes_goal = 1;
    boxes_left = 1;
}
```

Also, not sure why your ready button method isn't working, but make sure you have the boundaries correct, then have a global boolean variable called "playing" or "going" or something like that, and have that set to false. **Only call your ready button method (displaying it) if said boolean is false!** Once that button gets pushed, set the boolean to true.

Then, wherever you're running your code for displaying and interacting with your boxes/rectangles (main/draw method), put it all inside of an if-statement as such:

```
if(going){
    //everything to do with boxes should go here.
}
```

Inside that block of code, that's where it all goes down.

You said the goal was to click the first box one the screen, and when that box is clicked, remove it and put two new boxes on the screen, then once those two are clicked, make three new ones, correct? **Here's how I would go through that:**

1. Go through all of the boxes you have with a for-loop, and see if the box we're at is "hit."
2. If that box is hit, remove that box. Also, subtract one from boxes_left.
3. If boxes_left = 0 (no boxes are left on the screen), we finished that "scene" as you called it, but we don't need a "scene." Simply add one to boxes_goal, since we increase the goal each time we hit all the boxes. If there are still boxes left, we can just skip the next step!
4. Since there aren't any boxes left, we need to create some new ones. Use a for-loop to create the new boxes. *Hint: create an amount of boxes equal to amount_boxes!*
5. Display all the boxes that aren't hit!

**That should be it, I hope this helps and you can use it! Feel free to ask if you need help on anything else :)**

**Edit: I'll clarify the button deal for you:**

All my button class is:

```
void readyButton(){ 
    fill(255,0,0) //make it red
    rect((width/2)-100, (height/2)-40, 200,80);
}
```

To check if the button has been clicked and adjust the playing boolean accordingly:

```
void mouseClicked(){  
   if (!playing){
       if (*see if the mouse is over the button*){
           playing = true;
       }
   }  
}
```

So then in the draw part of your program:

```
if (!playing){
    readyButton(); 
}
```

Boom.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering, I can't figure out what the equivalent of 'void' and 'public' are on khan academy.

Comment: `Void` simply means that the method does not return anything. If you have a method called `String getName()` that method needs to return a String. Public, Protected and Private are visibility modifiers. Hope this helps!